# select random items from a sliding window in a list

Tags: python

I have an array `my_array` with integer items. I want to loop over `my_array` *x* times (e.g. *x* = 5), so `my_array` should be sliced in *x* chunks.

In the first iteration, I want to sample 10 percent of random items from the first chunk of `my_array` and in the second iteration, I want to sample 10 percent of random items from the second chunk of `my_array` and so on.

I tried

```
import random
percentage = 0.1
my_array = [3,6,9,8,7,1,2,4,5,19,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,20]
random.sample(range(len(my_array)), int(max(1,percentage * len(my_array))))
```

I can select random 10 percent items from the entire `my_array`. How can I make chunks and select items from relevant chunks? I want to efficiently do it even for variable length of `my_array`.

Comment: Why don't you just use the same code in a loop, where the start and end value of `range` are dependent on the loop index?

Comment: chunks need to have data randomly from my_array or in order from my_array?

Comment: @Ank chunks can be sliding window of array

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`numpy`** to do this efficiently.

**If chunks need to have data in same order from **`my_array`** (*rolling window*):**

Use [**`numpy.array_split`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) to create chunks. Then using list comprehension, select the random 10 percent items from each chunk:

```
import numpy as np
chunks = np.array_split(my_array, 5)
selected_items = [random.sample(list(chunk), int(max(1, percentage * len(chunk)))) for chunk in chunks]
```

###### Output:

```
>>> selected_items
[[6], [1], [11], [13], [20]]
```

**If chunks need to have data in random order from **`my_array`**:**

Use [**`numpy.array_split`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) along with [**`numpy.random.permutation`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html):

```
import numpy as np
chunks = np.array_split(np.random.permutation(my_array), 5)
selected_items = [random.sample(list(chunk), int(max(1, percentage * len(chunk)))) for chunk in chunks]
```

###### Output:

```
>>> selected_items
[[9], [12], [20], [4], [19]]
```

---

To get a list of selected items in each iteration, calculate the chunks, loop over them and pick 10 percent of items from each chunk:

```
import numpy as np
chunks = np.array_split(my_array, 5)
for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
    selected_items = random.sample(list(chunk), int(max(1, percentage * len(chunk))))
    print ("iteration ", i+1, ": ", selected_items)
    # do stuff with selected_items
```

###### Output:

```
iteration  1 :  [3]
iteration  2 :  [1]
iteration  3 :  [10]
iteration  4 :  [15]
iteration  5 :  [17]
```

Comment: Thanks, one small adjustment required, I do not want a list of lists, I want to get a list of selected items in every loop iteration e.g only 10% selected items from first sliding window in first iteration and so on

Comment: OK to do that, instead of list comprehension, just loop over the chunks and select the 10 percent items from each chunk in iteration.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include this. See the updated section at the bottom of the answer,

Comment: I tried your code (3rd section) but I get the following error TypeError: random_sample() takes at most 1 positional argument (2 given)

Comment: `random_sample`?  Its `random.sample` method from random module that you are already using in your code (in the question). Please check if you haven't made other changes in your code. From `random.sample` documentation, it takes 2 positional arguments not 1, and I just re-checked my code, it works fine.